# Can't change Apple TV Restrictions, grayed out

Tags: appletv

I can change Movie restrictions levels, but not TV.

I checked in iTunes and it is the same, grayed out.

How can I change the TV show restrictions levels when they are grayed out?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer on this thread.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250957805

If you are using Screen Time, there is an 'Allowed Content' area where you can set the TV show level which overrides and apparently grays out all other areas were you could set it.

So to fix it, go to:

System Preferences > Screen Time > Content and Privacy > Allowed Content

[image]